# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'TransactionHandlerDelegate'" (Swift/MAUI Interop)

Tags: ios, binding, sdk, frameworks, maui

I'm encountering an error while building an SDK, which states: "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'TransactionHandlerDelegate'; did you mean 'TransactionDelegate'?"

The `TransactionHandlerDelegate` mentioned in this error is part of a custom framework created by us outside the framework where the error is occurring. This delegate declaration is public.

[image: SDK-Swift.h]

Context:

```
1. The TransactionHandlerDelegate protocol is part of a custom
    framework developed by us. 
 2.It's declared as public for accessibility. 
 3.The error occurs in a different framework where the SDK is being integrated.
 4.The SDK targets compatibility with MAUI apps (potentially using Sharpie bindings).
```

Additionally, here's the code snippet for the `TransactionHandlerDelegate` declaration:

```
import Foundation

@objc public protocol TransactionHandlerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func onTransactionSucceeded(transactionStatus: TransactionStatus, data: Any?)
    func onTransactionProgressUpdate(transactionStatus: TransactionStatus,
                                      terminalStatus: TerminalConnectionStatus,
                                      description: String,
                                      data: Any?)
    func onReceiveTransactionData(status: TransactionStatus,
                                  data: Any?,
                                  additionalData: [String: Any])
    func onTransactionFailed(status: TransactionStatus,
                              terminalStatus: TerminalConnectionStatus,
                              error: String,
                              data: Any?)
}
```

Any insights into resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The excercise of adding the @objc we are eaddig for swift objective C interoprabilty since the SDK that we develop need to be accessed from MAUI app, since the sharpie bind is not working directly on Swift Implementation.